# Python equivalent of Ruby Array.wrap(item_or_array_like)

Tags: python, collections, type-coercion

I have a variable that might be an `Iterable` of `Mapping`s, or just a single `Mapping`, and I would like to coerce it to an `Iterable` of `Mapping`s, Similar to how Ruby's [Array.wrap()](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-c-wrap) works. This is a bit tricky because a `Mapping` is also an `Iterable`, and if I wanted a general purpose method, I wouldn't want it to treat strings like iterables either. It may not be easy in python because python doesn't make the distinction of implicit and explicit conversions quite like ruby does.

As a concrete example, say the variable can be as follows:

```py
var1 = [{'foo': 'bar'}]
var2 = {'foo': 'bar'}
```

in the case of `var2` it should be "wrapped" like `var1`, but `var1` when "wrapped" should be unchanged.

I want to duck-type this a much as possible, so I don't have to worry about specific types of the objects. I realize this is easier with `Sequence`s, but I see no reason why this shouldn't work with `Set`s as well.

But without those limitations you might try something like this:

```py
def wrap(item_or_collection):
  if isinstance(Sequence):
    return item_or_collection
  else:
    return [item_or_collection]
```

This works except for cases of Sets, Strings, Bytes, and some other "implicit" sequences that aren't really meant as collections in the same sense as things like Lists.

So any ideas or improvements? I could just handle all the edge cases with a nest of `if`s, but I'd like to avoid that if possible. Bonus if it's a small-footprint library utility.